# Retrieving data based on a delimited value

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm new to sql and I'm stuck with the following problem where I have the following 2 tables:

```
Table A
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|          ID         |     Email                                     |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|          12         | abc@gmail.com;123@gmail.com;456@gmail.com     |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|          13         | abc@gmail.com;678@hotmail.com                 |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|

Table B
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          Name       |     Email                                     |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          Mark       | abc@gmail.com;                                |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          John       | 456@gmail.com                                 |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          Alex       | 678@hotmail.com                               |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          Suds       | yyy@gmail.com                                 |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
    |          Eric       | zzz@gmail.com                                 |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
```

I now need to join the two tables but only show the Names of the users who have their email in Table A in which the the email column is delimited

```
|---------------------|
|          Name       |
|---------------------|
|          Mark       |
|---------------------|
|          John       |
|---------------------|
|          Alex       |
|---------------------|
```

Comment: Is the semicolon in the email for Mark intentional?

Answer (score 2):

This is a horrible data model -- and should be fixed.  Multiple values should not be stored in a single column.

That said, you can solve this with `join`:

```
select b.email
from a join
     b
     on ';' + a.email + ';' like '%;' + b.email + ';%';
```

Note the use of delimiters.  This matches the first and last elements of the list.

Comment: Does the above not match anything in between the first and last elements in the list?

Comment: @greasefirkins . . . It should be.  Are you having a problem?